# Excel Pivot Table column value update similar values upon refresh

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a question regarding excel pivot table.

I have a series of data in an excel spreadsheet. I created a pivot table using that spreadsheet successfully.

However when I edit the cell value of a cell in the pivot table, the rest of the values that are similar get updates/changes too.

Is the a normal behaviour of a pivot table? If I only want that cell to change to a new value and the rest of the cells below/above with similar values to remain as it is, how do I go about achieving that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is normal and is called "renaming of pivot table items" ([link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/rename-a-pivottable-field-or-item-HP005202103.aspx)).  I don't know what exactly you want to achieve by changing one instance of an item, but you can

- edit the concerned line(s) in your detail data table and refresh the Pivot
- manually group sub-items by selecting them, right-click -> Group and Show Detail -> Group ...